# Can I change pager.inc theme?

Tags: 6, paging

can I theme output of includes/pager.inc using drupal template system?

I want invert page links, I don't want any edit on pager.inc or CSS.

maybe invert items passed to theme_pager function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking here, you can override [theme_pager()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6) like any other theme function in Drupal. It is however quite a bit of code.

It's also relying on global functions, so you probably can't simply call the original fuction with reverted arguments.

Comment: yes, but I had this problem: http://drupal.org/node/457242, as you can see i solve it by remove theme registry row from cache table